# when is a finitely generated abelian group finite?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I've been asked to show that a finitely generated abelian group G is finite iff $G/pG = \{0\}$ for some prime number $p$, and to find a group such that that is true for all prime $p$. Not really sure where to start with this, I've tried finding a homomorphism with kernel $pG$ unsuccessfully. Hints or help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By the classification theorem, any FG abelian group is of the form $$\mathbb{Z}^d \times \mathbb{Z}_{d_1} \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_{d_i}$$
where $d_1 \mid \dots \mid d_i$.

Hint: what does $G/pG$ look like, if $d=0$ and if $d>0$ (that is, if $G$ is finite or infinite respectively)?

Comment: If it is finite, do you just use a prime factor of $d_1$ as your p?

Comment: That works, yes. (I think. I'm quite tired at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

For your second question: we know that multiplication by $p$ is an isomorphism for all $p$. So every element $g \in G$ must have some element $h$ such that $h + \dotsb + h = g$. So every element is infinitely divisible. Therefore look for groups where the ability to divide is of the essence.

Comment: So Q is an example of this?

Comment: @SimonMeans Yes.